# Pickup students without specifying starting locations

Tags: optaplanner

We need to do route planning for busses of a school, any student home can be a starting location for a bus, but we do not specify the stating location of any bus.

The solution we expect to have, will determine the starting location for each bus, and the round for each bus starting from a student location, ending at the school  and passing by students in order, where each bus can has up to 12 students for example:

We expect something like that:

34, 30, 27, 38, 30, 15, 10, 5, 8, 3, 2, 1,  0

21, 29, 23, 32, 11, 13,  9, 4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 0

..

..

..

where 0 is the school location index and others are students locations indices..

the algorithm has determined 34, 21 above as the starting locations of busses to meet the time window constraint.

Is this case possible to be implemented?
Any idea how to implement it? or is there example like it that we can see?

Answer (score 0):

**Just have the ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener traverse the chain in the opposite order.**

Normally it does:

[image: var listener]

In your case you have for example this chain:

- Vehicle A -> Student 1 (31km away) -> Student 2 (25km away) -> Student 3 (20km away)
- Vehicle B -> Student 7 (33km away) -> Student 8 (26km away) -> Student 9 (15km away)

Away meaning away from school.

Then your var listener goes like:

- student 3's arrival time = school start time - time from 3 to school (20km)
- student 2's arrival time = student 3's arrival time - time from 2 to 3 (>=5km)
- student 1's arrival time = student 2's arrival time - time from 1 to 2 (>=6km)
- ...

Comment: Thanks for answer, after searching I found that my case is called capacitated open vehicle routing problem (COVRP), is there an  example optaplanner vrp file for COVRP? as I am new to optaplanner

Comment: https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#examplesOverview

Comment: is OVRP listed here https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#examplesOverview ? could not find it..